# How to Cast values to decimal in Hive

Tags: hive, casting

This is example of the column "Amount" i am working on. I need to remove all '+' and '-' and all leading zeros, then convert to decimal. There are also cases when there is only zeros present and i am not sure what is the best approach for it. Is there a better solution? Please help on this.

```
     Amount
    -0000211
    +0000101
    +0000000
    +0000013

    CAST(CAST(CAST(Amount as INT) AS varchar(8)) as decimal(8,2)) from payment_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `abs()` to remove +/- and 0, and then use `cast()` to cast to decimal.

```
select CAST( ABS(Amount) as DECIMAL(8,2)) as ret_Amount -- this will return 211.00
```